# Why is my function giving me a hex value?

Tags: python, function, numbers

```
MAX_LINES = 3


def user_deposit():
    while True:
        deposit_amount = input("what is your deposit amount? ")
        if deposit_amount.isdigit():
            deposit_amount = int(deposit_amount)
            if deposit_amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("enter a valid amount please.")
        else:
            print("please enter a number.")

    return deposit_amount


def get_num_of_lines():
    while True:
        lines = input(
            "enter the number of lines to bet on (1-" + str(MAX_LINES) + ").")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if 1 <= lines <= MAX_LINES:
                break
            else:
                print("enter a valid line number.")
        else:
            print("please enter a line number.")

    return lines


def main():
    balance = user_deposit
    lines = get_num_of_lines
    print(balance, lines)


main()
```

I am trying to take the user's deposit and take the user's desired line. The whole project is essentially a text-based slot machine. I am a beginner, and I am essentially doing it with a guy from Youtube. I know that the hex value represents where the object is stored in memory.

Comment: Hey Diego. Please always tag your questions with the language & runtimes. As you may guess, `function` doesn't do it. I guess you need parenthesis: `get_num_of_lines()` and `user_deposit()`?

Comment: wow, thank you. Such an easy mistake, and thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

the reason you are getting the memory addresses for the functions is because both `balance` and `lines` are aliases to them. It seems as if you are trying to call those functions and assign the value they return to `balance` and `lines`. For this you have to `invoke` the functions by using `(` and `)`.

Good luck and welcome to Stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add parenthesis to the function calls in main().

Correction:

```
def main():
    balance = user_deposit()
    lines = get_num_of_lines()
    print(balance, lines)
```